# class ClassName* MethodName(int foo) const - what does it mean?

Tags: c++

I've been browsing code and came to see such construct in header file:

```
...
class ClassName* MethodName(int foo) const; 
...
```

ClassName is an class defined in other header file.
Edit:
To make question more clear. I was particulary interested in class keyword.

Comment: http://www.embedded.com/electronics-blogs/programming-pointers/4024450/Tag-vs-Type-Names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyword `class` is optional*.

So the (equivalent) line of code

```
ClassName* MethodName(int foo) const;
```

defines a function which

- takes an `int` as an argument
- returns a pointer to a `ClassName` instance
- promises not modify the instance on which it is called (the `this` pointer is const within the function)

---

*It's so uncommon that I didn't know that this was even possible to write. In C, you typically write `struct StructName` if you define a variable (or function parameter / return type) of some struct type. Since C structs are similar to the concept of classes (please not e that in C++, structs *are* classes) it seems like they allow both `struct` and `class` to be written in front of a struct / class name for compatibility reasons. C++ is designed to be able to parse C code almost unmodified (while they are two separate languages). So basically putting the keyword `class` or `struct` in front of any class name is meaningless.

Comment: Thanks for exact answer. I knew the other things, but I was really interested in, was using class keyword, as I seen it used multiple times. I guess it is used to improve readability of code then ?

Comment: Woah. Didn't expected that to compile either.

Answer (score 0):

it is so-called elaborated type specifier. It introduces a new class name in the declarative region. That is in your example ClassName is introduced as a new type.